# React Native app:installDebug Failed on 99%

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run my react native app on my physical samsung s7 edge running android 8.0,i have searched the internet and did a lot of things but not successful,the adb devices show the device,changed usb connection type but still no luck.

[image]

Comment: Hi what is the output of adb devices

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode in your Samsung S7 device?